# CV image latex code

Tags: graphics, positioning

I want to add a CV picture to add the right side in this section (see image). The picture must almost fit in the data section. I tried many things, but none of them is working. Does anybody how I can do that?

```
%Section: Personal Data 
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{Full Name:} & Rick  \\
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & place and birth \\
\textsc{Sex:} & Male\\

\textsc{Address:}   & address \\
\textsc{Phone:}     & +number\\
\textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:mail}      {mail!}\\
\textsc{Skype:}     & skype.name\\


\end{tabular}
```

[image: a busy cat]
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh89i.jpg)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use TiKZ to create an overlay image that does not disturb the rest of the layout. I don't know what packages you used to create the screenshot above, so I could not reproduce exactly your layout. That is one of the reasons why we insist on providing a minimum working example, (MWE) -- see my comment above. The following should get you started though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.north east) 
     {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{rick.jpg}};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{Rick}
\end{center}

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{Full Name:} & Rick  \\
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & place and birth \\
\textsc{Sex:} & Male\\

\textsc{Address:}   & address \\
\textsc{Phone:}     & +number\\
\textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:mail}{mail!}\\
\textsc{Skype:}     & skype.name\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe I misunderstood your question; if you want to put the picture *inside* the personal data section, you can use a multi-row cell in your table using the `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Data}
\begin{tabular}{rp{8cm}r} 
\textsc{Full Name:} & Rick  & \multirow{7}{3cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{rick.jpg}}\\
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & place and birth \\
\textsc{Sex:} & Male\\

\textsc{Address:}   & address \\
\textsc{Phone:}     & +number\\
\textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:mail}      {mail!}\\
\textsc{Skype:}     & skype.name\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. Love the picture of Rick Astley haha. One more question; how can I break a line in \textsc?

Comment: @rgroothuizen No problem :) I think what you really meant to ask is: how can I break a line inside a table cell? I think what you're looking for is: replace the 'r' in the column definitions in `\begin{tabular}{rp{8cm}r}` by e.g. `p{3cm}`?